# Installing a windows service on remote machine using given username

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, windows-services

What is the best way to install a windows service written in C# (in the standard way) on a remote machine, where I need to provide the username and password it should run as?

I am going to run it from MSBuild as part of integration tests.

EDIT: I don't have an msi and I don't want to create one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the [SC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) command.

> `sc.exe \\remotecomputer create newservice binpath= C:\Windows\System32\Newserv.exe start= auto obj= DOMAIN\username password= pwd`

(Note the spaces after the equals signs are important)

```
Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
SYNTAX: 
sc create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...
CREATE OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
       (default = own)
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
       (default = demand)
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
       (default = LocalSystem)
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

Comment: Looks really promising, but do I have to pay for it?

Comment: Its included in Windows, possibly in the Resource Kit, start a command prompt and type sc to see if its installed.

Comment: Just a note - if running this from powershell it is sc.exe not sc. sc is an alias for Set-Content in powershell. Just a little gotcha

Comment: Be careful with passing complex passwords with special characters as even double quotes around the password won't save you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296162/escaping-special-characters-in-cmd

Answer (score 1):

Installutil called from WMI invoked from Powershell is one way to go.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to do everything on remote machine.
At this time I saw naother solution called [PowerShell Remoting](http://get-powershell.com/2009/01/14/powershell-remoting-on-windows-2008-r2-server-core/), but haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth you checking out a utility I wrote which lets you install/uninstall/start/stop windows services on a local or remote machine. If you have a feature you need added let me know (comment/github issues or PM and I'll happily oblige).

[ServiceConfigurator on GitHub](https://github.com/Echilon/ServiceConfigurator)

As @Raj More suggested, it uses WMI invoked from .NET.

Comment: out of curiosity, how is it different from SC?