# Installing windows service on remote server

Tags: c#, windows, service

Is it possible to install Windows service on a server remotely? I'm trying to do that with sc directive but gives me error:

```
sc \\remote_computer_IP create svc binPath="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\svc\svc\bin\Release\svc.exe" start= auto obj= "DOMAIN\usr" password= pass
```

> [SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:
>
> Access is denied.

Comment: Are you an administrator of that machine?

Comment: @BugFinder yes, im admin

Comment: try running the sc remotely with say psexec

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159012/installing-a-windows-service-on-remote-machine-using-given-username

Comment: You probably can't do it that way if the two machines aren't in the same domain, because of [remote UAC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/951016).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish a connection using `net use`, instead of using PS remoting:

```
net use "\\remote_computer_IP\c$" "[PASSWORD]" /USER:"[USERNAME]" /persistent:no
sc \\remote_computer_IP create svc binPath="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\svc\svc\bin\Release\svc.exe" start= auto obj= "DOMAIN\usr" password= pass
net use "\\$ComputerName\c$" /USER:"$Username" /delete
```

This assumes that your target machine has the service located in c:\users\user.

SC.exe will not copy your svc.exe to the target machine. In my use case, I am deploying a windows service to a farm of web boxes, and my goal was to include my service in my existing web deployment using MSBuild. My solution was to:

- Deploy web components using MSBuild / Web Deploy (just like VS Publish)
- Deploy the service in the same manner

  - I created a web project to target a website dedicated to the service, just to leverage the rest of my MSBuild project files.
  - Thus, I wound up with my service in c:\inetpub\MyService\bin

Then I call:

```
sc create \\remote_computer_IP "MyService" binpath="C:\inetpub\MyService\bin\MyService.exe"
```

Powershell is awesome, but PS remoting can be a pain when dealing with VPN tunneling and remote server farms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do so with powershell, Microsoft recommends doing deployments and installations using powershell.

**[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5** means you did not run the command in elevated command prompt  (That is if you have Administrator access).

Here is a link that shows you how to deploy a windows service to a remote machine using powershell.

http://www.ben-morris.com/deploying-a-windows-service-remotely-with-powershell/